# how do I meshgrid 6 variates with numpy.meshgrid()?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 6 variate 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' in numpy.array format, and I want to use these variate to draw a 3D figure with matplotlib like below:

```
a = np.array()
b = np.array()
c = np.array()
......
```

then

```
x = f(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1)
y = f(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1)
z = f(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1)
```

finally

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)
```

so , how do I meshgrid these 6 variate?
I make it this way:

```
a1, b1 = np.meshgrid(a, b)
b1, c1 = np.meshgrid(c, d)
```

and it works with 3 variate, I want to know if it also works with 6 variate or there is another way?

Comment: Did you try `a1, b1, ... = meshgrid(a, b, ....)`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Instead of showing some abstract case, provide a [mcve] of what you are trying and in how far it fails. In general you can create a meshgrid of as many dimensions as you want, `q,r,s,t = np.meshgrid(a,b,c,d)`, but that will of course not make sense for plotting anything.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just want to draw a 3D figure. Usually we have 2 self-variate and 3 dependent variable(x, y, z), and we meshgrid the self-variate, then done. But now I have 6 self-variate, I dont know how to meshgrid them. Otherwise, I can draw it with 2-dimension loop.

Comment: @MaxPowers Yes, I tried 3D `a1, b1, c1 = np.meshgrid(a, b, c)`, it worked and I got 3-dimensional array. But there is no 4d meshgrid.

Comment: @S.Nan As @Importance already mentioned you may use `meshgrid` with as many dims as you like. However, defining a mesh of 6-dim vector space does not make any sense at all if you need to plot a 3-dim fig.

Comment: Please note that you cannot "just draw a 3D figure" from data in 6 dimensions. Hence you need to explain to us what you are trying to achieve; or else you will not receive any help here.

Comment: Create a toy example to demonstrate what you want instead of just describing it in text.  What  does your 6 variable look like? (e.g., its shape)